# Facebook API: Is it possible to upload thubnail along with CTA?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post a CTA url along with a custom thumbnail with my facebook post.
I am using /feed api.
I am aware that when CTA is passed along with the post, facebook will scrape the image from the URL's Open Graph image tag. Here my question is can we pass a custom image instead of facebook scraping the image from OG tag.

I tried uploading image and passing the media id but it didn't work.
Also posted the same on facebook community as well and got no response.

Can someone please suggest if someone has tried this?

Comment: Overwriting title / description / thumbnail of a link post to the feed is only possible, if you are the "owner" of the shared link, and have proven so by performing the Domain Verification process. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#custom-image